# add UIView as a subview in UITableViewController (or sliding up menu)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to add a subview in my UITableViewController. What I want to is when a user click a Navigation Bar Item, a small window or a subview will show which contains two buttons. When users click any button, the subview will disappear. I even have no success to add a subview in my TableViewController. I added following codes in ViewDidLoad:

```
UIView* simpleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,300,100)];

UIButton* add= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,240,300,100)];
add.titleLabel.text=@"here";
[simpleView addSubview:add];
[self.tableView addSubview:simpleView];
```

which did not work, the error is 
"setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key viewReference.'"
I change to     [self.view addSubview:simpleView]; ,which still did not work

Can some one tell me how to add a subview in a UITableViewController and provide some sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button frame rect is incorrect so your simpleView is fully transparent. Change

```
UIButton* add= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,240,300,100)];
```

to

```
UIButton* add= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40,300,100)];
```